# Where has the appViewDelegate.m file gone?

Tags: xcode, cordova

I am going through the cordova getting started tutorial.

It talks about an appViewDelegate.m file. But all I can see in the xcode Classes folder is the appDelegate.m.

What is going on here?

The url of the tutorial I am looking at is http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing it was renamed to this? Which tutorial do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use phonegap 3.3.0 and its docs.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide

And to answer your question: @keldar was right. It was renamed to appDelegate.m